# iOS : Write ByteArray ( [Int8] ) to a file in swift 4

Tags: java, ios, swift, swift4, filehandle

I am developing an application for **iOS** using **swift 4**.

I need to write **ByteArray** **[Int8]** to a file in **applicationSupportDirectory**.
And later i need to upload the file on my server to read it and do the operations.
My server is on java platform.

The problem is, i have to convert my ByteArray to **Data (NSData)** before writing in the file. But my java server is refusing to convert it back in **ByteArray[ ]**.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

1. How to write byteArray **Int8[]** to a file in **swift 4** in the same format as we write in java file.
2. how to read the file on my java server and retrieve the **byteArray []**

Any leads would be great.

Edit :
Adding Code :

```
let newByteArray: [Int8] = [62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 61, 0, 114, 0, 61, 0, 114, 0]
let data = Data(bytes: newByteArray, count: newByteArray.count)
let file: FileHandle? = try FileHandle(forUpdating: url)

    if file == nil {
        print("Failed to open file handler")
    } else {
        file?.seekToEndOfFile()
        file?.write(data)
        file?.closeFile()

    }
```

Now i don't know how to read it back from the file and convert it to original input.
Also how to read the file on my server, using java platform.

Sorry if it is an stupid question, i am too new with swift and iOS.

Comment: have you tried reading the byte array in swift4 after writing them in swift4 ? so that it's make sure that your byte array data is written flawlessly.

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: @RatulSharker i tried and it was not same. :(

Comment: you need to make sure, ios can write and read consistently before getting it to the java based server application.

Comment: Show us the code that you use to read your file and verify that it contains the bytes from `newByteArray`. Then, show us the code that takes that file or data and uploads it to your server.

Answer (score 1):

A Byte in Swift is an UInt8 object. If you have a collection of Int8 coming from Java and would like to save your data to disk you would need to first convert it to a collection of bytes `[UInt8]`:

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0, 127, 128, 255]

let toInt8 = bytes.map(Int8.init)         // [0, 127, -128, -1]
let backToBytes = toInt8.map(UInt8.init)  // [0, 127, 128, 255]
let data = Data(backToBytes)
```

---

In your case

```
let newByteArray: [Int8] = [62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 61, 0, 114, 0, 61, 0, 114, 0]

let data = Data(newByteArray.map(UInt8.init))
print(Array(data))  // [62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 62, 0, 113, 0, 61, 0, 114, 0, 61, 0, 114, 0]
```

Once you convert your Int8 array to Data you can use Data's write method to save it to any directory in your App Sandbox

Comment: I am trying just the contrary of it. I am writing collection if Int8 and writing to a file and uploading it to the server. And Java side, i need to convert this file back into Int8 collection ( ByteArray )

Comment: Leo, Thankyou so much for this.  Can you please tell me how to write Data(newByteArray.map(UInt8.init)) in a file and read it back exactly same ??